# Facebook SDK for Javascript, FB.login() callback not firing (async call never gets a response?)

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-ads-api

The below code is my Facebook API `javascript` so far. It's pretty simple, with a bunch of `console.log()`s to follow the code flow. (I recognize that naming arguments response and response2 is terrible practice but it's just what I put quickly for now to avoid naming conflicts).

As it stands, `FB.init()` succeeds, `FB.getLoginStatus()` works, and the two `FB.api()` calls work, but `FB.login()` never happens. It is async though so the `console.log()`s just before and just after do execute. To summarize, my console output is:

> makes it here
>   makes it here too
>   Permissions:
>   Object {data: Array[37]} 
>   Good to see you, my-name-is-here.

I guess it's because the async `FB.login()` call never gets a response so the callback never fires, thus no `console.log()`s from inside the function. But I need this `FB.login()` in order to get extended permission `ads_management`. Any idea what is wrong, or at least a direction to go about solving this myself?

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

  FB.init({
    appId: 'my-app-id-is-here',
    xfbml: true,
    version: 'v2.0'
  });

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {

    if (response.status === 'connected') {

      FB.api('/me', function(response2) {
        console.log("Good to see you, " + response2.name + ".");
      });

      FB.api('/me/permissions', function(response2) {
        console.log("Permissions:");
        console.log(response2);
      });

      console.log("makes it here");
      FB.login(function(response2) {
        console.log("why not here?");
        if (response2.authResponse) {
          console.log("Response to login asking for ads_management permission");
          console.log(response2);
        } else {
          console.log("User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.");
        }
      }, {
        scope: 'ads_management',
        return_scopes: true
      });
      console.log("makes it here too");

    } else {

      // filled with other code that doesn't effect this question yet

    }

  });
};
```

#### UPDATE:

Taking away the parameters argument `{scope: 'ads_management', return_scopes: true}` makes the `FB.login()` call at least be attempted, but in the console there is now the error:

> "FB.login() called when user is already connected."

but I thought the way to get more permissions when the user is already logged in IS by calling `FB.login()` again, with the desired permissions specified in the parameters argument.

Answer (score 1):

Your flow is not correct. First check for the permission in the `FB.api("/me/permissions")` **callback** (since the facebook api calls are asynchronous), and then if that particular permission is not yet granted, then call `FB.login()`.

Here you go-

```
if (response.status === 'connected'){
    FB.api('/me/permissions', function(response){
        var hasPermission = false;
        var response = new Array();
        response = response.data;
        response.map(function (data) {
            if (data.permission == "ads_management" && "status" == "granted") {
               hasPermission = true;
            } 
        });
        if(!hasPermission)
            // call FB.login() here
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use oauth:true in your FB.init.

And you should check by code if you don't already have needed permission before issuing FB.login.